# Allow to use a question as a duplicate target if its only answer is yours

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

Today I've encountered an issue with a question that was very similar to a question that I answered a couple of months ago.

The answered question was asked by a new user, who didn't have enough reputation to upvote the answer and they didn't accept the answer (only left a comment that the answer helped them).

Since this happened in a pretty obscure tag [prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prometheus), my answer didn't get any upvotes from passing by users.

In the normal situation, I would vote to close a new question with a link to the older one, and that all. But since the older question doesn't have any accepted or upvoted answers - it is not possible.

I suggest allowing to use a question as a duplicate target even if it has has a single unaccepted unvoted answer, if its only answer is yours. This will allow to propose question closure to a new OP without awkward comments exchanges.

And anybody other who will want to use the same question as a target, will still be required to upvote an answer first.

Comment: You *could* just post a comment on the question you feel is a duplicate, in the usual format "Does this answer your question? [Allow to use question as duplicate target if its only answer is yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426128/allow-to-use-question-as-duplicate-target-if-its-only-answer-is-yours)" and *if* the answer on the other question is helpful then likely the user will: 1. Let you know it is a duplicate 2. Upvote your answer on the other question so you can 3. Flag/Vote to close as an *actual* duplicate.

Comment: Looks like a moderator did the honours here anyway - so presumably they can bypass the requirement https://stackoverflow.com/q/76954686/73226

Comment: @ThomA, yes. But this will work only if two conditions are met at the same time: new OP can vote, new OP will vote.

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes, I was helped in this instance by moderator, after discussing this a bit in SOCVR. And this feature request came from there too.

Comment: In paragraph 3, what are "stranded" users? (If a typo then fix and I will delete this comment.) I support the question, there are too many duplicates on this site.

Comment: I don't see why there should be a special case for the target having an answer that was written by the user who want to vote as a duplicate. Why not just allow duplicate closures regardless of who answered the target? Frankly, even the requirement on the target having any answers at all feels unnecessary to me, since a question can be a duplicate whether it's answered or not.

Comment: Too refine the feature request I guess it is "if its only answer is yours and it does not have a negative score"? I'm in two minds on this request TBH. There is maybe more of an incentive to dupe close inaccurately if you already have an answer on the dupe target but otherwise if you *know* it is a dupe then annoying you obviously can't just upvote the answer vote to close and get on with your day in this case and no alternative workflow

Comment: @AdrianHHH, it was supposed to mean users who got lost in tags and came to question by chance. But since then I've found my erroneous understanding of word "stranded".

Comment: @cigien, regarding votes: if you want to close a question that is answered by somebody else - you can simply upvote answer before VTCing. Regarding targets without answers - I don't know, it feels like major breaking changes, that are hard to justify, and even less so to get implemented with the current state of affairs within network. But generally I would agree with your idea.

Comment: @MartinSmith, by "unvoted" I mean question that wasn't voted: neither up, nor down. I'm not sure I have a strong position on +n/-n questions, but right now I'm inclined to say that they should not be a part of proposed exception. Regarding incorrect dupe-targeting: since this will be an exception for only one user, it shouldn't be a problem. It might tip some balance for gold tag owners, but I don't see how they are stopped from wrong targeting duplicates right now (and as an example: [recent meta post about such case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426094))

Comment: Unfortunately I think it would need to work in the opposite way to avoid abuse: let users vote to close as a dupe of a question with a single unaccepted, un-upvoted answer _that isn't theirs_. Otherwise users may become close-vote happy just to try and redirect views to their own content (abuse).

Comment: @TylerH But users can already do both of those things, one in _every_ case, and the other in almost all relevant cases.  They can already close as a dupe of a question with a single unaccepted, un-upvoted answer that isn't theirs, because they can upvote it and then vote to close (there's also nothing stopping them from retracting the upvote after, although I don't think we'd look too kindly on that if we noticed). (...continued in next comment)

Comment: And they can close as a duplicate of any question on which they've provided an answer that is either upvoted or on a question with at least one answer that is.  And even then, if they don't have a gold badge, they still need two other users (or one gold badger, or the asker) to agree with them to get the question actually closed as a duplicate.  And if they _do_ have a gold badge, they can do so unilaterally as long as the answer is upvoted, which any user with a gold badge certainly has no shortage up.

Comment: @RyanM Yes I mentioned that self-realization in chat a while ago :-) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/56599811#56599811

Comment: “Why not just allow duplicate closures regardless of who answered the target?”  - This is already the case, except the only requirement, is an answer have a single upvote. This requirement even extends to users with a gold badge in a tag. Only moderators can close a question unanimously

Comment: This is not really encouraged, but sometimes you might want to gamble by posting the "same" answer on the new question, see which one is upvoted, then vote to close another question as a dupe (and self-delete the answer from the now-dupe question as clean-up).

Comment: @cigien There is no point in muddying the waters in regard of the "duplicate question" definition when some people still don't understand the current definition.

Answer (score 3):

The existing checks are an important safeguard. The point of closing questions as duplicates is that they "have an answer" at the target question. If it turns out that a lot of people are asking the same silly thing, *it needs to have a reasonable quality answer* as well as a reasonable-quality question in order for us to consider the matter resolved; otherwise we are only telling new askers "hey, you aren't the only one who wonders about this", which is not useful.

If you believe that you have noticed a pattern of the same question being asked, and want to establish a canonical, you should be able to convince the community that the canonical is adequate for the needs of people who ask the question. This is **especially** true if the canonical you propose is self-answered. Just because you're a diligent curator who has noticed something important, *doesn't prove* that you're *also* a competent subject-matter expert.

If your answer "helped" the first person who asked, that doesn't imply that it's an adequate answer to the question that will satisfy others as well. After all, *"helping" people ([whatever that means](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)) isn't the motive here; answering questions is*. Of course, sometimes new users who reasonably ought to accept an answer just don't; and of course, the system has a bone-headed idea about the OP's assessment of the answer being special compared to everyone else's (i.e. new users can't just upvote it, meanwhile the accept mark gives 15 rep and is separately tracked). However, if *nobody else* is upvoting an answer, that isn't a great sign.

If you have extenuating circumstances (like what you describe here, including the part about the tag being unpopular), asking a moderator for assistance is appropriate. In more popular tags (such as Python) you might consider asking in a corresponding open chat room if people would be willing to *review* your proposed canonical; but of course, don't ask for upvotes or otherwise do voting-ring things.

Comment: I consider myself an expert in Prometheus questions more than curator. And I wanted to close question to avoid answering it with the same answer - nothing more (exactly as you said - answering question, not helping people). I don't see this as a "canonical" answer - mere duplication of the question.

Comment: Additionally, I don't see how to ask moderators for help in adequate way: moderators advised against custom flagging such questions, and looking for a chance to "catch" moderator in some room is unsustainable. For me it is easier to leave such question open, if system doesn't want me to do curation.

Comment: Also, I don't think such a problem can occur in a popular tags like mentioned python. If your answer really answers question, you'll easily get a couple upvotes in first hour. Most of answers in prometheus don't get this even within a first year.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm completely sold here.  Asking moderators via flags to close questions doesn't work very well, as it tends to require subject matter expertise (in this case, I used a combination of it seeming somewhat clear + my perception of markalex's subject-matter expertise, but that's not always viable).

Comment: It's also a vote that the potential close voter would be able to cast for a question answered by _literally anyone else_ simply by casting a single upvote. Maybe there could be a safeguard like the gold-badge unilateral closure not working, but the current protection is so little that I question if it's worth the cost of someone being unable to vote to close a question that they know is a duplicate, because they wrote the answer to the target.